# Dropdown is not binding on the basis of selected value in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to bind my state Dropdown list from the database on the basis of country.
country drop down is working fine but state drop down is not filling.
however i am getting the id of  state drop down in console.
Here is the dropdown list

```
<div class="inputList flyLabel">
                                                        <select class="input" ng-model="Customer.CU_State">
                                                            <option ng-selected="Customer.CU_State==option.id" ng-repeat="option in StateList" value="{{option.ID}}">{{option.Name}}</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <label class="title {{'Customer.CU_State' !=''?'active':''}}">State</label>
                                                    </div>
```

And getting value thorough ajax call 
here is the code

```
 $scope.getcustomer = function () {
    this.UserId = '@userId';
    var CU_UserId = UserId;
    //console.log(CU_UserId)
    $http({
        url: '/api/customer/getcustomerdetailsft/' + CU_UserId,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: JSON.stringify(CU_UserId),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
        .success(function (data, status) {
            //console.log(data)
            debugger;
            $scope.Customer = data;
            $('.inputField flyLabel').addClass('active');
            $('.inputList flyLabel').addClass('active');
            $('.inputField .title').addClass('active');
            $('.inputList .title').addClass('active');
            $scope.Customer.CU_FirstName = data.cU_FirstName;
            $scope.Customer.cU_PhoneNumber = data.cU_PhoneNumber;
            $scope.Customer.cU_ProfilePicture = data.cU_ProfilePicture;
            var removetime = data.cU_DOB
            var dateonly = removetime.replace('12:00:00 AM', '')
            $scope.Customer.cU_DOB = dateonly;
            $scope.Customer.CU_Country = data.cU_Country;
            $scope.Customer.CU_State = data.cU_State;
```

In **$scope.Customer.CU_State** i am getting the Id of state but not able to fill the id in dropdown.

Please suggent any idea i will be very thankful.

here is the id in console

[image]

Comment: How are you populating StateList? Have you checked it gets properly filled?

Comment: First i am submitting value in database then getting the values it is filled properly.